# R: how to use foreach for a pre-specified number of replicates like in a while loop

Tags: r, foreach, parallel.foreach

```
library(foreach)
library(doMC)


myfun <- function(threshold){
  val <- rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  if(val > threshold){
    stop("bad")
  }else return(val)
}

results <- vector("list", length = 10)
parallel_fun <- function(reps, threshold){
  registerDoMC(cores = 48)
  results = foreach (j = 1:reps, .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
    myfun(threshold)
  }
}

> parallel_fun(reps = 10, threshold = 0)
 Error in { : task 1 failed - "bad"
```

The above is a simple, reproducible example. I want to parallelize `myfun` for a total of `reps = 10` replicates. `myfun` may stop if the `val` that was generated is greater than some `threshold`. In that case, I want to stop running `myfun` and not have it return `val`. In the end, I want my `results` to have 10 `vals` that are greater than some `threshold`. Therefore, I thought maybe a while loop would be more appropriate here, since I want to keep it running until I have 10 values that satisfy the `threshold`. Is it possible to re-purpose `foreach` for parallelizing a while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Control flow

Using exceptions for control flow is often discouraged. Ideally,

### Use function that already does what you want

In this specific example, you are simulating truncate normal distribution. So you could use `truncnorm` function from the [truncnorm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/truncnorm/truncnorm.pdf) package.

### Rewrite the function

Alternatively, rewrite the `myfun` to always return correct value:

```
myfun = function(threshold){
    repeat{
        val = rnorm(1, 0, 1)
        if(val <= threshold)
            break
        }
    val 
    }
```

This is just one of the possible variants. Here I am using a custom `do-while` construct.

Note that depending on the threshold, a large or potentially infinite number of iterations might take place, so tread carefully and either put a maximum number of iterations in place or do some preliminary checks if `threshold` is not outside of a maximum range of the function in question, ideally both.

With this, you should be able to run `foreach` easily as you are doing right now.

### Write a wrapper

If you don't have control over the `myfun`, you need to construct wrapper, the construct might be almost identical to the function above:

```
wrap_myfun = function(threshold){
    repeat{
        val = try(myfun(threshold))
        if(is.numeric(val))
            break
        }
    val
    }
```

### Keeping track of iterations:

If you need to keep track of the number of iterations it took you to generate said numbers, you can just rewrite the `repeat` into a `for` cycle or just add counter and another option:

```
wrap_myfun = function(threshold, .maxiter=10^9, .default=NA){
    iter = 1
    repeat{
        val = try(myfun(threshold))
        if(is.numeric(val))
            break

        if(iter >= .maxiter){
            val = .default 
            break
            }

        iter = iter + 1
        }
    list("value"=val, "iterations"=iter)
    }
```

Alternatively, instead of assigning default value, you can use `stop("maximum iterations reached"). That depends on how serious is the problem.

This way, you have moved all the logic into the data generating function and you do not have to manage the queues implemented in the `foreach`. The load should be distributed among the cores equally (past the potentially randomly long computation time for some iterations, but that is something you cannot influence).

Comment: Thanks. For `if(val > threshold) break`, it should be `if(val <= threshold) break` correct? Because I want the values to be <= the threshold.

Comment: @Adrian yes, sorry, didn't pay enough attention. Fixed with an edit. Upvote if you want, but I would suggest waiting few hours before accepting.